# Obtener Historial de un Chat en vivo SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla llamada **livechat** quiero obtener solo el ultimo mensaje del contacto al que se le envíe o reciba el mensaje preferentemente por ID del contacto. Suponiendo que soy el Contacto 1 debería obtener

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con algo simple pero solo logre obtener toda la lista de mensajes.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
"SELECT * FROM livechat WHERE Chat_Fecha = (SELECT MAX(Chat_Fecha) 
 FROM livechat 
 WHERE Chat_De_IDpersonal = '$idpersonal' 
 OR Chat_A_IDpersonal = '$idpersonal') ORDER BY Chat_Fecha DESC"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo asi "SELECT * FROM livechat WHERE Chat_Fecha = (SELECT MAX(Chat_Fecha) FROM livechat WHERE Chat_De_IDpersonal = '$idpersonal' OR Chat_A_IDpersonal = '$idpersonal') ORDER BY Chat_Fecha DESC"

Comment: OR Syntax WHERE condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3

Comment: Eso es para que no muestre el mensaje 9 que no pertenece al Contacto 1 pero supongo que  no me  he explicado bien

Comment: Probaste el sql en phpmyadmin?

Comment: SI claro y solo quiero obtener en una consilta sql las lineas 6 y 8 de una lista creciente de usuarios y si te fijas la linea 9 no pertenece a mi usuario que se llama Contacto 1

Answer (score 3):

Para lo que estas buscando, necesitamos dos querys. Uno que nos diga cual seria el ultimo mensaje recibido por el usuario, con origen en otro usuario. Y luego de ello, el mensaje en si.

Por lo que entendi, queremos los mensajes que recibio el usuario (que esta en este campo chat_A_IDpersonal ), para lo cual, necesitamos ese campo en la condicion de where.

Y vamos a tener que agrupar por el campo de quien envio el mensaje (Chat_De_IDpersonal ) y obtener la mayor fecha (de Chat_Fecha )

Esto lo hacemos asi:

```
Select Chat_De_IDpersonal, Max (Chat_Fecha ) as fecha
from livechat 
where chat_A_IDpersonal  = {el id del destinatario}
group by Chat_De_IDpersonal
```

Eso nos va a dar el ultimo mensaje que nos enviaron, de todos los que nos enviaron mensajes. En realidad, nos da la fecha del ultimo mensaje. Para obtener el ultimo mensaje real, tenemos que unir esta tabla, con si misma, para obtener el mensaje que queremos. y para ello, hacemos lo siguiente:

```
Select c.chat_mensaje, c.Chat_De_IDpersonal,c.Chat_Fecha 
from livechat l inner join 
    (Select Chat_De_IDpersonal, Max (Chat_Fecha ) as fecha
    from livechat 
    where chat_A_IDpersonal  = {el id del destinatario}
    group by Chat_De_IDpersonal) c on l.Chat_Fecha  = c.fecha and l.Chat_De_IDpersonal = c.Chat_De_IDpersonal
where chat_A_IDpersonal  = {el id del destinatario}
```

Esto ultimo lo que hace, es conseguir el mensaje para la ultima fecha de cada uno que envio.

---

## **Notas re importantes**

- Tener el id y el nombre del usuario en la misma tabla esta directamente **mal**. Viola lo que son los conceptos de base de datos en tercera forma normal. Miralo de esta forma, si el usuario quiere cambiar su nombre, tenes que tocar todos los registros que lo contienen. El nombre del usuario debe estar en otra tabla, con los datos del usuario.
- Si podes asegurar que el id crece con los mensajes siempre, en lugar de buscar por fecha maxima, podes buscar por id maximo. va a ser un poco mas rapido todo.
- Usar el nombre de la tabla en los campos (chat_mensaje, chat_fecha) es una antiguedad que se usaba en los años 80. Si podes, evitalo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Estos nombres solo son temporales para no perderme  y dividirlos por nos nombres de las tablas. Creo que ya estamos cerca de resolver este problema mio. Me puedes explicar esta linea porfavor: c on l.Chat_Fecha  = c.fecha and l.Chat_De_IDpersonal = c.Chat_De_IDpersonal

Comment: @OrielC. no hay nada temporal en los nombres.. o despues vas a hacer un replace de todo tu proyecto para arreglar los mismos? haceme caso, usa los nombres que van.

Comment: @OrielC. esa linea es la condicion para que se unan las tablas mediante el join. Si no sabes lo que es un join, corre a la documentacion de SQL y fijate para que funciona. Es uno de tus mejores amigos.

Answer (score 2):

Imaginemos que quieres obtener toda la información del último mensaje enviado al `Contacto 3`. Haríamos la siguiente consulta a la base de datos:

```
SELECT * // Todas las columnas
FROM livechat // Tabla donde vamos a recoger la información
WHERE Chat_A_IDpersonal = '123456789' // ID del usuario del que queremos obtener la información
ORDER BY Chat_Fecha DESC // Ordenamos por fecha de forma descendente
LIMIT 1; // Obtenemos solo 1 registro
```

Comment: El problema es que esto no muestra el contacto al que se le envió el mensaje o del que se recibió el mensaje

Comment: Mira [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida, no tienes que simplemente decirle que hacer, y que copie y pegue la respuesta, la idea es que se entienda porque lo haces de esa manera y que hace exactamente

Comment: El problema es que eso me ajora el ultimo mensaje que no pertenece al contacto 1. Solo quiero obtener el mensaje  6 y 8  que son los ultimos de cada contacto (Contacto 2, Contacto, 3) Gracias.

Comment: Entonces para ello lo único que tienes que hacer es hacer una consulta a la base de datos y quedarte con todos los usuarios que han mandado uno o más mensajes a un usuario en concreto. Una vez lo tengas guardado, por ejemplo en un `array`, haces la consulta de arriba con el id de cada usuario que tienes almacenado. De ese modo tendrías todos los últimos mensajes que se han enviado desde usuarios distintos a un usuario en concreto.

Comment: Bueno esto me muestra correctamente el mensaje 8 pero sera una lista creciente de usuarios y no puedo colocar esta linea                                WHERE Chat_A_IDpersonal = '123456789' por que soy el Contacto 1 se supone  con la ID 338007654